# How to make use of a new SCSI drive in a VPS hosting FTP server?

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ftp

I just had configured a Virtual Server (Ubuntu Server 16.04, GNU/Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64) for FTP use. For these means I got initially assigned a SCSI drive, mounted as sda with to partitions sda1 as SWAP and /dev/sda1 as ext4. The problem is, I requested more storage resources as current sda2 was running out of free space. So, I got informed 1000G were assigned to my VPS and to check this *df* command shows me the following:

```
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
udev             2.0G      0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs            396M   5.8M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda2         13G    12G  269M  98% /
tmpfs            2.0G      0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M      0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            2.0G      0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs            100K      0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs            396M      0  396M   0% /run/user/1001
```

Problem is, after checking using *lsblk* I realise there's a physical device which is not formatted so I used *fdisk* to do so but still I can't make use of that new *sdb1* partition as *df* command does not shown any changes, mounting is not working as *sdb1* is not found and that I can confirm as it is not in the */etc/fstab* file. Current *lsblk* output is:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0   16G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  2.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda2   8:2    0 13.2G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 1000G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 1000G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

whereas *lsblk -f* shows:

```
NAME   FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
fd0                                                             
sda                                                             
├─sda1 swap              e22cb8bf-167b-415e-b1e4-7f3709ca201f   [SWAP]
└─sda2 ext4              651cd80e-1401-4c44-9d42-226ab9901b8f   /
sdb                                                             
└─sdb1 LVM2_member       fl4MDC-BlqJ-rI2o-aeXP-eJc6-shbx-EJIzG0 
sr0
```

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/cryptsetup.8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget what you know about Windows and drives.

Ubuntu has a file system that can accommodate an infinite amount of disks and still have them all under the same file system (the [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) *Read this in its entirety after following below steps*).

So what you want to do is:

- Take a full system backup of your server
- Take another full data backup just in case
- Create a new partition table on `/dev/sdb` (it's now an LVM2 member: we don't want that)
- Create a new partition on `sdb` using an `EXT4` file system
- Mount that file system somewhere temporarily:

  ```
    mount /dev/sdb1 /media/NewFTPFiles
  ```
- Stop the FTP Server
- Copy all files from the old directory to the new one, preserving all attributes:¹

  ```
    cp --preserve=all --recursive /srv/ftp /media/NewFTPFiles
  ```
- Delete all old files to free up space: **Dangerous and why you made 2 backups**

  ```
    rm --recursive /srv/ftp
  ```
- Unmount the new disk:

  ```
    umount  /media/NewFTPFiles
  ```
- Mount the new disk *in  the same exact location as the old server's files were originally*

  ```
    mount /dev/sdb1 /srv/ftp
  ```
- Start the FTP server
- Ensure you now fix your `fstab` file with the new mount command so that next time you reboot the server the mount is done at boot time.

#### Voilà!

`/dev/sdb1` is now overlayed on your file system in `/srv/ftp` and `df` and `du` will show all that new space allocated to the FTP service and `/` will be cleaned up!

<sub>**Note ¹:** I use `vsftpd` and that uses `/srv/ftp`.  Substitute that with whatever directory your FTP server uses...</sub>

Comment: Hi Fabby! Thanks a lot for the detailed reply and apologies for the long delay. It worked perfectly, I would only add a few small basic details in case another newbie like me finds it useful. 1) The directories must be created before mounting. For example, /srv/ftp must be created before typing `mount /dev/sdb1 /srv/ftp`. 2) FTP service is stopped using: `/etc/init.d/vsftp stop`
To start the FTP service type: `/etc/init.d/vsftpd start`

Comment: no worries: I noticed (and upvoted when I saw the acceptance. 1. You never mentioned which FTP deamon you're using so `/srv/ftp` is just an example. 2. See #1  **:-)** So the above explanation is generic and can apply to any FTP daemon...  **;-)** if I make it too specific, someone else using another FTP daemon would not be able to use it.  **;-) 0:-)**